# How to fix OS(Ubuntu hard drive not present error) in EFI?

Tags: uefi

I am using dell-inspiration 14r,Last day, when I shutdown ubuntu, Next time It didn't boot, It said hard-drive not found, try reseating it. But It ,Again,could detect the hard-drive from boot menu.I tried many things, Nothing seemed to work. At last, I downloaded a booted lubuntu 13.04 and installed it. Now the grub bootloader menu comes up asking me which to boot. I changed boot option's from legacy to UEFI. Now In both the booting System, Ubuntu says that boot/efi is not ready, press S to continue.How to fix this error? Also How Installing lubuntu get's me to the login screen again?

Edit: I also found that when I try to boot in EFI mood, It tells `start pxe over IPv4` Now, When I enter to the boot menu I see at #1 Ubunt(hard drive not present) that is bios is not detecting My OS. So the problem here is, Ubuntu isn't been able to boot itself.That's why installing lubuntu I was able to boot. Now what should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably got filesystem damage on your [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. This type of damage is often caused by the Windows Fast Startup feature, which can do serious damage to filesystems on a dual-boot configuration. It's ***imperative*** that you disable this feature when dual-booting with Windows. See [this page](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) for instructions on disabling this feature.

***After*** you disable Fast Startup, you may also need to repair filesystem damage on the ESP. You can do this in Linux with the `dosfsck` command, as in `sudo dosfsck /dev/sda1`; however, you'll need to know what partition to pass as an argument, as that varies from one computer to another. Type `sudo parted /dev/sda print` to see your partition table. The ESP can be identified as a FAT partition with its "boot flag" set. Alternatively, you can use `CHKDSK` or its GUI equivalent in Windows, but I'm less sure of the exact procedure there, so I can't provide details. In a worst-case scenario, you might need to copy all the files off of the ESP, create a fresh FAT32 filesystem on it, and copy all the files back. If you do this, you'll probably have to adjust your `/etc/fstab` file in Linux to get the partition to mount correctly, since its serial number ("UUID," although it's not technically a UUID) will probably have changed.

Comment: I don't have a windows OS, I just have Ubuntu.I think the problem might be in bootloader. The thing is , I accidentally tried to format my entire hard drive with disk utility while I was trying to format a usb-flash.. may be that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the BIOS. You will need to enter your bios. Disable UFEI boot and enable legacy support. In other words you need to disable secure boot. I had this same error on a brand new HP Pavilion out of the box; where I wiped windows 8 for a clean ubuntu 13.04 server. Let me know if you have any questions.